# Struggling with polynomial Long Division in $GF(256)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, finite-fields

I'm currently trying to build a QR Code generator, which has lead me to studying a bit of abstract algebra - more specifically, finite fields.

I've studied quite a bit on my own and I'm at the point where I'm trying to implement an algorithm for polynomial long division in the $GF(256)$, but my results don't match with the neither the QR Code specification examples nor with [this tutorial](https://www.thonky.com/qr-code-tutorial/error-correction-coding) that I have been following as well. So I thought I could perform a quick polynomial division here to see if I can figure out if I actually understand the whole process as a whole.

I'm going to divide $p(x) = 5x^4 + 32x^3 + 27x^2 + 7x + 3$ by $q(x) = x^2 + 5x + 1$.

I start out by multiplying $q(x)$ by $5x^2$, which gives me $5x^4 + 17x^3 + 5x^2$ (here I use the fact that each element can be represented as a power of the primitive. So $5 \cdot 5 = (\alpha^{50})^2 = 17$). Then, I add this result with $p(x)$, which gives me $49x^3 + 30x^2 + 7x + 3$ (also, here I use the fact that every element in this field can be represented as a polynomial with coefficients being $0$ or $1$. This means that an addition is equivalent to a XOR operation of bit the respective bit strings).

I then repeat this same process two more times:

- Multiply $q(x)$ by 49x, resulting in $49x^3 + 245x^2 + 49x$, to then add it to the remainder of the previous operation, giving me $235x^2 + 54x + 3$.
- Multiply $q(x)$ by 235, resulting in $235x^2 + 48x + 235$, to then add it to the remainder of the previous operation, giving me $6x + 232$, which is the final remainder.

Therefore, the **quotient** is $5x^2 + 49x + 235$ and the **remainder** is $6x + 232$.

Am I doing something wrong? If so, then what? I'd appreciate any kind of feedback.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you taking for the base field? The splitting field over degree $8$ polynomial?

Comment: I'm extending the field $GF(2)$ using the primitive polynomial $p(x) = x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + 1$.

Comment: Why do you think your result is wrong?

Comment: The QR Code specification says that the error correction code words are the coefficients of the remainder polynomial after a polynomial long division. My result doesn't match with neither the example in the specification nor with the example in the tutorial I linked in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I made a crash course for [Pari](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/Events/PARI2019/talks/finitefields.pdf) and used an [online version](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/gp.html) and got

```
? c=ffgen(c^8+c^4+c^3+c^2+Mod(1,2))
% = c

? divrem((c^2+1)*x^4+(c^5)*x^3+(c^4+c^3+c+1)*x^2+(c^2+c+1)*x+(c+1),(x^2+(c^2+1)*x+1))
% = [(c^2 + 1)*x^2 + (c^5 + c^4 + 1)*x + (c^7 + c^6 + c^5 + c^3 + c + 1), 
     (c^6 + c^4 + c^2 + c)*x + (c^7 + c^6 + c^5 + c^3)]~
```

The symbols ? and % are the input and the output prompt.
I hope I did use this Pari calculations correctly.

Now I used Maxima (I used my Windows version) to check if I used the correct polynomials. I substituted $c$ by $2.$

```
(%i) (c^2+1)*x^4+(c^5)*x^3+(c^4+c^3+c+1)*x^2+(c^2+c+1)*x+(c+1), c=2;
(%o) 5*x^4+32*x^3+27*x^2+7*x+3

(%i) x^2+(c^2+1)*x+1, c=2;
(%o) x^2+5*x+1

(%i) (c^2 + 1)*x^2 + (c^5 + c^4 + 1)*x + (c^7 + c^6 + c^5 + c^3 + c + 1), c=2;
(%o) 5*x^2+49*x+235

(%i) (c^6 + c^4 + c^2 + c)*x + (c^7 + c^6 + c^5 + c^3), c=2;
(%o) 86*x+232
```

In Maxima %i is the input prompt and %o is the output prompt.

There is a [Maxima online version here](http://maxima.cesga.es/index.php). Simply input

```
(c^2+1)*x^4+(c^5)*x^3+(c^4+c^3+c+1)*x^2+(c^2+c+1)*x+(c+1),c=2;
(x^2+(c^2+1)*x+1),c=2;
(c^2 + 1)*x^2 + (c^5 + c^4 + 1)*x + (c^7 + c^6 + c^5 + c^3 + c + 1),c=2;
(c^6 + c^4 + c^2 + c)*x + (c^7 + c^6 + c^5 + c^3),c=2;
```

and press *Clic.*

So  in $GF(256)$ the quotient is $5x^2+49x+235$ and the remainder is $86x+232.$

These calculations were done very poorly, but I am not familiar with the tools. I only want to show you there are tools to make such calculation that are error prone if you do them by hand.

---

To calculate this by hand the coefficients should be seen as polynomials.

So $12$ is binary $1100$ is the polynomial $1 \cdot c^3+1\cdot c^2 +0 \cdot c + 0.$

If you ad two numbers you have to add the two polynomials which means for each power you add the coefficients. Because the calculations are modulo 2 you simpli can XOR the digits of the numbers.

To multiply the numbers you have to multiply the polynomials and if there highest exponent is 8 or higher you have to divide  the result by your irreducible polynomial and take the remainder. A more efficient way is to use the [Log-/Antilog-tables](https://www.thonky.com/qr-code-tutorial/log-antilog-table), e.g.
$$ 235×5=2^{235}×2^{50}=2^{235+50}=2^{285}=2^{30}=96 $$ The exponent must be reduced modulo 255.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your source a bit: In your case the numbers are not actually used as numbers, but as polynomial with their coefficients encoded by the binary digits of that number.

So then note that $235\times 5\neq 48$:
$$ 235\times 5= 235 + ((235\times 2)+285)\times 2+285 = 96$$

This gives you then a remainder of $86x+232$.

Comment: the exponents must be calculated modulo 255, it seems that the OP calculated them modulo 256

Comment: So in your example multiplication is carried out normally and addition is equivalent to the XOR operation?

Comment: @melosomelo Yes, kind of. The multiplication by $2$ is merely a bit shift that represents a multiplication of $P(t)$ with $t$. This is reasonable as we assume that $\deg(P)<n$. The $+$ then means the actual addtion in $\mathrm {GF}(256)$, which means component wise addition, thus bitwise xor.

Comment: @melosomelo Note that a number $b_{n-1}\ldots b_0 = b_0+b_12 + \ldots + b_{n-1}2^{n-1}$ corresponds to $b_0+b_1t+\ldots + b_{n-1}t^{n-1}$. So to calculate $a\cdot b$ we can simply use a linear evaluation: $a+(b_0+tR) = b_0\cdot a + t\odot (a\cdot R)$ where $t\odot x$ is $tx = 2x$ if $2x<256$ else $tx + m = 2x + 285$.

Comment: @melosomelo At the moment it is not clear to me what Lazy is actually doing but multiplication canbe done  by using the [logarithms](https://www.thonky.com/qr-code-tutorial/log-antilog-table) $235 \times 5 = 2^{235}\times 2^{50}=2^{235+50}=2^{285}=2^{30}=96$

Comment: @miracle173 I was actually doing that, but apparently I used mod 256 instead of 255 (as you said earlier).

Comment: Is that the only mistake that you could find? @miracle173